# What's the spectral soft-thresholding operator when the matrices are complex?

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, regularization, nuclear-norm

\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
    \min_{X} \, \frac{1}{2}\|X-Y\|_{\text{Fro}}^{2}+\lambda\|X\|_{*}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

where $X, Y \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ and $Y$ is given. $\|\cdot\|_{*}$ denotes the nuclear norm. What's the solution?

If the matrices are real, the problem has an analytic solution known as the *spectral soft-thresholding operator*. But I don't know what the solution is when the matrices are complex. Do the solutions have the same form?